# How to edit rails generator views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, generator

I am using rails 4.2.6 and I wanted to edit default generator views. A generator which is:

```
 Rails g controller index about
```

On this generator I am getting views but I want to edit that default views for that I am using this folder structure under:

```
#lib/templates/erb/controller/view.html.erb

 <h1><%= class_name %>#<%= @action %></h1>
 <p>Find me in <%= @path %></p>
```

For scaffold editing works perfectly when I used this: lib/templates/erb/scaffold/index.html.erb

I just want to know how to overwrite this controller views. My solution is not working. And thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Are you trying to edit the actual generated view? In that case it would live in `app/views/indexes/about.html.erb` since the first argument to `rails g controller` should be the name of the controller. If you are looking the override the other generator templates they should be in [`/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates/`](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/erb/scaffold/templates)

Comment: When I run rails g controller index I just want to change this. I mean the generated files by using that I need to change view.html.erb. And I don't know why it is not working